# StyleCopのSA1200の意味を教えてください

Tags: c#, visual-studio

通常、usingディレクティブはnamespaceの外（ファイル先頭）に記述しますが、StyleCopを使用すると以下の警告が発生します。この意味を教えてください。

```
SA1200 : CSharp.Ordering : All using directives must be placed inside of the namespace.
```

Answer (score 1):

SA1200は次の２つの理由から警告の対象となっています。

> 1. Placing using-alias directives within the namespace eliminates compiler confusion between conflicting types.
> 2. When multiple namespaces are defined within a single file, placing using directives within the namespace elements scopes references and aliases.

詳しくは[StyleCopt SA1200](http://www.stylecop.com/docs/SA1200.html)のドキュメントを参照してください。

Answer (score 1):

次のBlog記事で取り上げられているようなusingでエイリアスを使い、そのエイリアスと同じ名前の方がnamespaceないで使用されても、そのエイリアスがnamespaceの外にあった場合コンパイルエラーにならずバグが発見されないという問題もあるため、コンパイラがこのバグを見つけられるようにする目的があると思います。

[Stylistic differences in using - I know the answer (it's 42) - Site Home - MSDN Blogs](https://web.archive.org/web/20151223110758/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/abhinaba/archive/2006/08/21/709051.aspx)

ただ、最近のMSがOSSとして公開しているコードでもこのルールが適応されているコードはあまり見掛けないので、このルールはそっと外してしまっても良いかなと思っています。

ただ、usingでエイリアスを多用するコーディングスタイルを取る場合には設定しておいた方が無難かもしれません。